# UIView reusability

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have two ViewControllers - `FirstViewController` & `SecondViewController`. `FirstViewController` is has a `tableView` and `customTableViewCells`. Each `cell` has dynamic content. On selection, user is taken to the `SecondViewController`

`SecondViewController` is the detailed representation of the selected `cell`. In `SecondViewController` I have a `bannerView` which is same as that of the `FirstViewController`'s selected `cell`'s `contentView`. It works perfectly.

But the thing is, I am recreating the entire `FirstViewController`'s `cell`'s `contentView` again in `SecondViewController`'s `bannerView`. I just doubt if could reuse the `contentView` some how in `SecondViewController` without recreating it. Ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Go ahead and create a xib file for it. Load it everywhere you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the UIView class to create your custom view and add it as subview to the cell's content view.